# Handling error response from PYCURL

Tags: python, curl, ftp, pycurl

I relatively new to python, but have been writing some basic scripts for my job to check the status of files on specific servers by ftp. I understand there are better modules for ftp, but due to security restrictions on our work computers we are limited to the basic modules installed on our system which need to handle ftp, sftp, and ftps. Pycurl is the only module we can currently work with.

Now pycurl works successfully at testing the connection by printing the directory and pushing or pulling a file to or from a server via ftp, sftp, fops. Thats not our current issue. The issue is the error response that Pycurl spits out. It doesn't display the ACTUAL error that occurred that you would see from verbose. If we put the wrong remote directory it continue to connect after showing the error in verbose then say something like "Could not access user certificates". WE would like to hand the errors so they display what actually occurred. We saw options such as BUFFERERROR but we haven't figured out how to use them properly. basically, if a sever name is incorrect we would like it to say that.

Does anybody have some experience with pycurl? or know of any debugging script to catch and display the actual errors? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Stackoverflow is better suited for more specific questions. Provide self-contained code snippets, output and error information and it's much more likely you'll get help.

Answer (score 1):

you can debug the error by making use of VERBOSE

```
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL,url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' + token)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```